# Setting the first number in the y axis of a Python bar graph to 0

Tags: python

I'm trying to make the first number of the y-axis in my Python bar graph 0. There are currently only 2 values on the y-axis, and they are both values (temperatures) for my Gold Coast and Sunshine Coast figures on the x-axis. I want the y-axis to begin at 0 and ideally end at 25.

```
import pylab as plt

LocationNo = [1,2]
Temp = [16, 23]

LABELS = ["Gold Coast", "Sunshine Coast"]

plt.bar(LocationNo, Temp, align='center')
plt.xticks(LocationNo, LABELS)
plt.show()
```

I've tried using the `.set_ylim(ymin=0)` code but had no luck.

Comment: I don't understand your question, because my output starts at zero. Which matplotlib version do you use? Otherwise you could define the y-axis limits with `plt.ylim(0, 30)`

Answer (score 0):

`.set_ylim` is a member function of the axes in the plot and uses a [different API](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim.html). 
At the plot level you have two options [according to the `matplotlib` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html):

Using defaults:

```
plt.ylim(ymin=0,ymax=25)
```

Setting explicitly:

```
plt.ylim(0,25)
```

Comment: @Mr. T: Thank you for the advice, I clarified my response